# NTLDR error message and the WPF

Tags: wpf

I am building an application using the WPF. This application is for presentation purposes, the user can draw shapes, write text play audio and video ...etc. but I have an error message about the NTLDR when I am running the application on the Windows XP and actually I do not have any clue of where I can find the problem.

I would appreciate if anyone has any hints regarding where I can search in the code to find the problem or any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That NTLDR is nothing to do with your WPF application, that is a boot loader problem, it sounds like the boot sector is kaput and could not find the boot loader file called [NTLDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLDR) which is 'NT LoaDeR' responsible for bringing up the system. You may be well advised to read the contents about NTLDR on wikipedia as there at the bottom of the page, a useful link to how to fix up the 'NTLDR is missing' error message.

This link is replicated [here](http://tinyempire.com/notes/ntldrismissing.htm) for your convenience on how to troubleshoot this problem. Also is this [link](http://www.techsupport.me.uk/2009/02/20/is-your-ntldr-missing/) that explains how/why it happens.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Tom for your reply, actually I found where is the problem, it was from the NSIS installer. I use the NSIS istaller instead of MSI to install the application on the client's PCs, and after many searches I found that people who use the NSIS installer face the same problem and that the NSIS remove the NTLDR from the root folder during the setup process (I do not know why) :)

Thanks again for your help, Hamzeh.

Comment: To cerrect what I posted earlier, the problem was in the Windows XP ghost that the system admin guy installed it on the PC. :S